# Failed to execute child process? Anyone know a fix for this?

Tags: 10.04, firefox, command-line

I changed something that I did not mean to change and now everytime I try to open **Firefox** it says:

```
could not launch application, failed to execute child process "firefox" (No such file or directory).
```

Aybody know a fix for this? I am using ***Backtrack 5 r3*** with ***Gnome***, which is based off of **ubuntu 10.04**.

Comment: `I changed something that I did not mean to change` - what is that?

Comment: I wish I knew, but unfortunately I have completely forgotten. I am a newbie at this stuff. I installed backtrack just to mess around on and maybe learn some stuff. I think it happened when I was trying to install TOR. The problem occurred a few weeks ago and I just ignored it because I was a little clueless as to how it had happened. I tried to use it firefox today and got that error.

Comment: What is the output of `which firefox`? Mind if you re-install firefox?

Comment: when i type, which firefox, nothing happens, it just brings up a new line. I was thinking about trying apt-get install firefox, but I wanted to see if there was a way to rescue it first. I feel like it is probably still installed, but the directory has maybe changed or something, I don't know.

Comment: You no more have the binary file(the executable file) of your firefox, I am not sure whether you can recreate it without re-installing it.

Comment: just tried apt-get install firefox and it says it's already the newest version. Does that mean it's still there? If so where would it be located in the file system. And how would I completely remove firefox so when I do apt-get it will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have lost the binary file of Mozilla firefox. By lost, I mean it has either been renamed/replaced/moved/deleted; any of these. If you do not know what has actually happened and can afford to lose your firefox data(browsing history, saved passwords, etc.) then the easiest way to procure the binary is to re-install the complete package.

To re-install, open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get purge firefox
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Comment: You can backup the `~/.mozilla/firefox/` folder before purging btw. This way, the data can be restored after re-installation by restoring that folder.

Comment: I wish I had of known that but too late now. Thanks anyways for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by not running the application as a root user, therefore create another user and launch the application from there it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW.  Export the Address Books from Window > Address Book > Tools > Export.

Make your own Bookmarks backups to ensure you have the latest.  The Mozilla auto saves here may not necessarily contain your last changes.

Restore your, say, pop.gmail.com mail first.

Save the, say, /home/user/.mozilla/seamonkey/?#$%^&().default/Mail/pop.gmail.com/msgFilterRules.dat file.  After updates you can put it back into the .default file in the same position.  That file name will not be the same again!  But you will have your filters back. If your Inbox structure was changed after your last msgFilterRules.dat backup, you will have to Choose folders again for every filter.