# What is the easiest way to remake the deleted binary file of package?

Tags: binary

I just went through [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376408/failed-to-execute-child-process-anyone-know-a-fix-for-this) and was wondering whether there was a better way to re-create the binary of an installed package, which got deleted somehow.

I know I can reinstall the application, but re-installing the complete package isn't necessarily feasible always.

**P.S.:** I am talking about an installed application, so please assume that I don't have the source code(it may be open-source but I don't want to procure the exact source code of the installed version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, DEB packages are extractable!

So, you can simply download the DEB package, extract it, take the binary from it and place it where it should be inside your system (this is visible from the DEB's structure, anyway).

For example, let's say that you're missing a binary file.

Download the DEB package using this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PACKAGE=$1
URI=$(apt-cache show $PACKAGE | grep "Filename:" | cut -f 2 -d " ")
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/$URI
```

It takes as argument the package.

Then, you extract the package and you will see a `usr` folder and inside it a `bin` folder (this is usually where the binary package is being installed). So, you copy this binary file to `/usr/bin` and you are done.

Be careful NOT to download later versions of the package than the one that you had installed in your system in order to avoid incompatibility problems!

EDIT: After a constructive comment by [chaos](https://askubuntu.com/users/185729/chaos) please note that if you have already installed the package in your system then you can find it in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`. Taking the package from there is a good idea, because you can be sure about the incompatibility issues.

Comment: If it's a previously installed program you may have the .deb package still in the `/var/cache/apt/archives/` folder. Anyway +1 good answer.